# Eloquent Laravel relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables **books** and **users** .
How I can get the users have books its **id** smaller than 6 using Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: How do you currently get books? The way to get an answer suited to your situation is to explain what you have accomplished so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to post some more info about your intended schema along with your models (i.e. `Book.php` and `User.php`)

Looking at your schema it looks as though your `Book` model has a `has many` relationship with users. Where you say, "I want books to be related to users where books.id not exceed 5." If I understand what you are saying, you can use `Book::where('id', '<=', 5)->get()`. That will give you all of the books with ids [1,2,3,4,5].

I recommend reading the Eloquent docs here: [Laravel Eloquent Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Here are some quick snippets I threw together that may help get you started with your Eloquent models.

```
/**
 * Define Models
 */

// User.php
class User extends Eloquent { }

// Book.php
class Book extends Eloquent {

    # ...

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }

    #...

}


// routes.php
Route::get('test/{book_id}', function($book_id)
{
    $book  = Book::find($book_id);
    $users = $book->users;
    return compact('book', 'users');
})
```

Then you can navigate to '/test/3' and this will display (as JSON) the book as well as the book's users.

Either that or (and i would recommend this) just open up tinker `php artisan tinker` and play around with that a bit.

Like I said, you would need to provide some more info if you need help beyond that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your database

**books** This table should have: (id , user_id, name)
**users** This table  should have: (id , name)

Your User model should have:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

   public function books() {
      return $this->hasMany('Book', 'user_id');
   }

}
```

Your Book model should have:

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

   public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('User');
   }
```

Query

```
$user = User::find(1);
$book_count = $user->books()->count();
```